# How to enumerate *all* Javascript globals in a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, global-variables, introspection

I'm looking for a programmatic way to get a list of browser globals, including built-in constructors like `Array`, `Object`, etc.

If I type Javascript in the Chrome console, I get this somewhat odd behavior:

```
console.log('Array' in globalThis);  // true

const s = new Set(function*() { for (const key in globalThis) yield key; }());
console.log(s.has('Array'));  // false
```

That is, I can check if the `Array` constructor is in the global object, but when I enumerate its members the `Array` constructor is not there.

My questions:

1. Why doesn't my approach of enumerating keys work?
2. Is there a programmatic and cross-browser way (only evergreen browsers is okay) to enumerate every member accessible through `globalThis`?
3. Failing that, are there programmatic browser-specific ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Properties on an object need not be **enumerable**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NiettheDarkAbsol is correct in the comments that not all properties are enumerable. It turns out to be possible to enumerate "non-enumerable" properties anyway though, by using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` (and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()` if you need them) to get direct properties. If you need inherited properties as well, you'll need to do this over the prototype chain.